# User authentication for Twitter API using Python application

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth, twython

I am working on a module for an application written in Python (it is open-source). I want the module to allow a user to log into Twitter and update status (post a tweet). I have Python script I wrote using the twitter import that requires a developer (me) to put in consumer/authentication token/secrets. I don't want to have the tokens pre-programmed into the module, but rather have a user log in to update THEIR status (obviously).

I need a general direction to pursue. I envision the user clicking on a Share! menu option, a browser popping up with the Twitter login page, a user logging in and the application storing the credentials, and then updating the status from there. I have the module working, but like I said before, I need to input token information from my application's apps.twitter.com page. I want the user to be able to log in.

Here is a snip of code using the twython library:

```
from twython import Twython

#APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET
OAUTH_TOKEN = '...'
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = '...'
APP_KEY = '...'
APP_SECRET = '...'

twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
if (twitter.update_status(status='The status is updated from Python!')):
    print("Working!")
else:
    print("Not working!")
```

The code above works and updates my Twitter status, but I do not want other users of this module to be updating my status, but rather have them log in and update their status.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT
What I have now:

```
import urllib.parse
import oauth2 as oauth

consumer_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
consumer_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
request_token_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token'
access_token_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token'
authorize_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize'

consumer = oauth.Consumer(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
client = oauth.Client(consumer)
resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "GET")

if resp['status'] != '200':
    raise Exception("Invalid response %s." % resp['status'])

request_token = dict(urllib.parse.parse_qsl(content))
print("Request Token:")
print("    - oauth_token        = %s" % request_token[b'oauth_token'].decode())
print("    - oauth_token_secret = %s" % request_token[b'oauth_token_secret'].decode())

print("Go to the following link in your browser:")
print("%s?oauth_token=%s" % (authorize_url, request_token[b'oauth_token'].decode()))

accepted = 'n'
while accepted.lower() == 'n':
    accepted = input('Have you authorized me? (y/n) ')

oauth_verifier = input('What is the PIN? ')
token = oauth.Token(request_token['oauth_token'], request_token['oauth_token_secret'])

token.set_verifier(oauth_verifier)
client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)

resp, content = client.request(access_token_url, "POST")
access_token = dict(urllib.parse.parse_qsl(content))

print(access_token.keys())
print(access_token.values())
print("You may now access protected resources using the access tokens above.")

import twitter
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key=' ', consumer_secret=' ',
                  access_token_key=' ', access_token_secret=' ')
tweet = api.PostUpdate("First tweet from an authenticated user.")
```

I get to the point where I authorize my application with the login, the webpage redirects to the callback_url, just like it should, but I don't get a PIN to input. Where does that come in?

Comment: The OAuth workflow requires a Web app that can handle the callback, as explained in the Twython docs: https://twython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/starting_out.html#authentication - Alternatively, your app could host a server whose address you specify in the callback. Since you haven't shown any code that attempts to do that, your question is too broad and might result in closure unless you update the code to demonstrate what you've tried.

Comment: The application is desktop based, so there is no webpages involved. Would the app hosting a server be configured in apps.twitter.com? Frankly, I have not tried much on the user authentication side, but will try your suggestion and update as I find out more information. @JoeMayo

Answer (score -1):

i know it late but it can be help others

you can find verify token after your app verify and it will be show into header.